# ODBC convert postgres citext column in SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server, odbc

I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL to SQL Server server as a linked server.

On the SQL Server, I have installed the ODBC driver for PostgreSQL (psqlodbc_09_02_0100-x64). I created a system DSN to a specific database on the PostgreSQL. This DSN works correctly.

Using SSMS I created a linked server that created successfully. When I test the connection it says successful and when I expand I can see all the tables from postgres.

The select I am running is: select * from [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[TableName]

I have 2 issues now:

1 - When selecting from a table that has a column with citext this select throws an error:
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "linkedserver" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "columnName" (compile-time ordinal 5) of object ""Database"."schema"."tablename"" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.

2 - I would like to put a limit on the select but when trying select top 10 it gives me all 34,00 rows in the postgres table.

I do not have access to make any changes on the postgres side but I can change configurations in the ODBC driver and SQL Server which I have tried to play around with but no success.

Comment: Ever figure this out? lol just ran into it

Comment: I ended making a view on the postgres side that selects everything from the table and convertss each citext column to plain text and then on the SQL side I just selected from that view.